# Kotlin Set to Null If Not Null

Tags: null, kotlin

Is there an idiom in Kotlin for setting a variable to null if it is not already null? Something more semantically pleasing than:

```
var test: String? = null
if(test != null) test = null
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [execute if not null idiom](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#execute-if-not-null):

```
test?.let { test = null }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just assign null to local variable:

```
test = null
```

In case if it's not null - you assign null to this variable.
In case if variable is null - you just assign null to it, so nothing changed.

Comment: 1) I suggest adding this as a comment to the question instead of as an answer as this doesn't actually answer the question. 2) If it is null - something does happen: an assignment. For simple properties setting it to `null` is not a problem but for properties with a backing property, etc. I can see why one might want to only set it to `null` if it isn't already `null`.

Comment: But we have concrete case - defined variable, not property.

Comment: True. Perhaps you could clarify that if it is `null`, an assignment does happen but it just sets the variable to the same value: `null`.

Comment: I know this is the better way to do it, but I was asking specifically about Kotlin idioms.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this extensions which makes this simpler:

```
inline fun <T, R> T.letThenNull(block: (T) -> R): T? { block(this); return null }
val test: Any? = null
...
test = test?.letThenNull { /* do something with test */ }
```